# loading data with llama-index after upgrading package can't find readers file

Tags: python-3.x, large-language-model, llama-index

I recently upgraded my llama-index module.  Now when I try to run the lines of code below I'm getting the error message below.

The llama-index related packages I have installed currently are:

```
llama-index               0.10.17                  pypi_0    pypi
llama-index-agent-openai  0.1.5                    pypi_0    pypi
llama-index-cli           0.1.8                    pypi_0    pypi
llama-index-core          0.10.17                  pypi_0    pypi
llama-index-embeddings-openai 0.1.6                    pypi_0    pypi
llama-index-indices-managed-llama-cloud 0.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
llama-index-legacy        0.9.48                   pypi_0    pypi
llama-index-llms-openai   0.1.7                    pypi_0    pypi
llama-index-multi-modal-llms-openai 0.1.4                    pypi_0    pypi
llama-index-program-openai 0.1.4                    pypi_0    pypi
llama-index-question-gen-openai 0.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
llama-index-readers-file  0.1.8                    pypi_0    pypi
llama-index-readers-llama-parse 0.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
llama-index-vector-stores-chroma 0.1.5                    pypi_0    pypi
```

Does anyone see what the issue might be and can you please suggest how to fix it?

code:

```
# Load data into 'Documents' a custom type by LlamaIndex
from llama_index.core import SimpleDirectoryReader

documents = SimpleDirectoryReader('./data').load_data()
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/anaconda3/envs/llama_index_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/core/readers/file/base.py:22, in _try_loading_included_file_formats()
     21 try:
---> 22     from llama_index.readers.file import (
     23         DocxReader,
     24         EpubReader,
     25         HWPReader,
     26         ImageReader,
     27         IPYNBReader,
     28         MarkdownReader,
     29         MboxReader,
     30         PandasCSVReader,
     31         PDFReader,
     32         PptxReader,
     33         VideoAudioReader,
     34     )  # pants: no-infer-dep
     35 except ImportError:

ImportError: cannot import name 'DocxReader' from 'llama_index.readers.file' (unknown location)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 11
      7 import llama_index.readers.file
      9 from llama_index.readers.file.docs import DocxReader
---> 11 documents = SimpleDirectoryReader('./data').load_data()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/llama_index_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/core/readers/file/base.py:465, in SimpleDirectoryReader.load_data(self, show_progress, num_workers, fs)
    460         files_to_process = tqdm(
    461             self.input_files, desc="Loading files", unit="file"
    462         )
    463     for input_file in files_to_process:
    464         documents.extend(
--> 465             SimpleDirectoryReader.load_file(
    466                 input_file=input_file,
    467                 file_metadata=self.file_metadata,
    468                 file_extractor=self.file_extractor,
    469                 filename_as_id=self.filename_as_id,
    470                 encoding=self.encoding,
    471                 errors=self.errors,
    472                 fs=fs,
    473             )
    474         )
    476 return self._exclude_metadata(documents)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/llama_index_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/core/readers/file/base.py:360, in SimpleDirectoryReader.load_file(input_file, file_metadata, file_extractor, filename_as_id, encoding, errors, fs)
    329 """Static method for loading file.
    330 
    331 NOTE: necessarily as a static method for parallel processing.
   (...)
    357     List[Document]: loaded documents
    358 """
    359 # TODO: make this less redundant
--> 360 default_file_reader_cls = SimpleDirectoryReader.supported_suffix_fn()
    361 default_file_reader_suffix = list(default_file_reader_cls.keys())
    362 metadata: Optional[dict] = None

File ~/anaconda3/envs/llama_index_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/core/readers/file/base.py:36, in _try_loading_included_file_formats()
     22     from llama_index.readers.file import (
     23         DocxReader,
     24         EpubReader,
   (...)
     33         VideoAudioReader,
     34     )  # pants: no-infer-dep
     35 except ImportError:
---> 36     raise ImportError("`llama-index-readers-file` package not found")
     38 default_file_reader_cls: Dict[str, Type[BaseReader]] = {
     39     ".hwp": HWPReader,
     40     ".pdf": PDFReader,
   (...)
     54     ".ipynb": IPYNBReader,
     55 }
     56 return default_file_reader_cls

ImportError: `llama-index-readers-file` package not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :`from llama_index.readers.file.docs.base import DocxReader, HWPReader, PDFReader`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip install -U llama-index-vector-stores-chroma
pip install -U llama-index-readers-file
```

You can use `pip show llama-index` to view its dependencies, and use `pip list` to check if you have these dependencies in the environment. If don't, just `pip install` them.

If the issue persists, try force reinstalling the package without using the cache

```
pip uninstall llama-index
pip install llama-index -U --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall
```

This problem was answered in github: https://github.com/run-llama/llama_index/issues/11336